# object.assign does not work on different types with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Just imagine I have 2 html tables next to each other. Each table has an array of unassigned pupils or assigned pupils for a certain test. With 2 buttons you can move those checkbox-selected pupils to the other html table.

The pupils in both html tables have nearly the same properties.

When I use Object.Assign then I get an compile error:

```
properties gradeScorePairs is missing in type {} and UnAssignedPupil
```

To fix that error I just copy/paste the same properties on both objects...

Thats a workaround but not solution for me. I use Typescript 2 and transpile to ES5.

What possibilities do I have with object.assign and different types for source/target to solve this problem?

**AssignedPupil.ts**

```
import { GradeScorePair } from './gradeScorePair';
export class AssignedPupil {

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
    }

    id: number;
    name: string;
    gradeScorePairs: GradeScorePair[];
    isSelected: boolean;
    selectedGradeScorePair: GradeScorePair;
}
```

**UnAssignedPupil.ts**

```
import { GradeScorePair } from './gradeScorePair';
export class UnAssignedPupil {

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
    }

    id: number;
    name: string;
    // gradeScorePairs: GradeScorePair[]; // don`t need it on the unassigned html table
    isSelected: boolean;
    // selectedGradeScorePair: GradeScorePair; // don`t nee it on the unassigned html table
}

  unassignPupil() {
    var i = this.assignedPupils.length;
    while (i--) {
      var p = this.assignedPupils[i];
      if (p.isSelected) {
        let assignedPupil: AssignedPupil = this.assignedPupils.splice(i, 1)[0];
        let unAssignedPupil: UnAssignedPupil = Object.assign({}, assignedPupil);
        unAssignedPupil.isSelected = false;
        this.unAssignedPupils.push(unAssignedPupil);
      }
    }
  }

  assignPupil() {
    var i = this.unAssignedPupils.length;
    while (i--) {
      var p = this.unAssignedPupils[i];
      if (p.isSelected) {
        let pupilToAssign: UnAssignedPupil = this.unAssignedPupils.splice(i, 1)[0];
        let assignedPupil: AssignedPupil = Object.assign({}, pupilToAssign);

        // Difference are these 2 lines of code
        assignedPupil.gradeScorePairs = this.gradeScorePairs;
        assignedPupil.selectedGradeScorePair = null;

        assignedPupil.isSelected = false;
        this.assignedPupils.push(assignedPupil);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the compiler that this empty object is of type `AssignedPupil`:

```
let assignedPupil: AssignedPupil = Object.assign({} as AssignedPupil, pupilToAssign);
```

That will clear the error.

The thing is, that when doing that you won't really have an instance of class `AssignedPupil`, you'll have an object with the same properties.
You won't have errors because of the [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#Introduction) nature of typescript.

If you intend to use that class as a data object only then you're fine (but why not just using interfaces?), but if you plan to have class methods then the variable `assignedPupil` won't have those.

---

#### Edit

An example:

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }

    distance(other: Point) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x - other.x), 2) + Math.pow((this.y - other.y), 2));
    }

    toString() {
        return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
    }
}

let a1 = new Point(0, 0);
console.log(a1.x); // 0
console.log(a1); // Point {x: 0, y: 0}
console.log(a1.toString()); // (0, 0)

let a2 = Object.assign({} as Point, a1);
console.log(a2.x); // 0
console.log(a2); // Object {x: 0, y: 0}
console.log(a2.toString()); // [object Object]

console.log(a1.distance(a2)); // 0
console.log(a2.distance(a1)); // Uncaught TypeError: a2.distance is not a function
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20distance(other%3A%20Point)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x%20-%20other.x)%2C%202)%20%2B%20Math.pow((this.y%20-%20other.y)%2C%202))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60(%24%7Bthis.x%7D%2C%20%24%7Bthis.y%7D)%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20new%20Point(0%2C%200)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a1.x)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%0D%0Aconsole.log(a1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Point%20%7Bx%3A%200%2C%20y%3A%200%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(a1.toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20(0%2C%200)%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%20as%20Point%2C%20a1)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a2.x)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%0D%0Aconsole.log(a2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bx%3A%200%2C%20y%3A%200%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(a2.toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5Bobject%20Object%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(a1.distance(a2))%3B%20%2F%2F%200%0D%0Aconsole.log(a2.distance(a1))%3B%20%2F%2F%20Uncaught%20TypeError%3A%20a2.distance%20is%20not%20a%20function))

Comment: Both pupil objects are just data objects for now.

Comment: So cast it to `AssignedPupil` and the error goes away. But if that's the case, then there's no need for classes, use interfaces.

Comment: I am coming from C# being TS newbie. BUT interfaces can`t be instantiated and I am still creating those UnAssignedPupils/AssignedPupils from server data their I have to new up both object types from json.

Comment: You only initiate part of the objects. You can do: `Object.assign(new AssignedPupil(), pupilToAssign)` which will instantiate a new `AssignedPupil` and then assign the values, but you'll need to deal with an empty constructor.